# Growable vector on the stack with fixed capacity

Tags: c++, c++11, vectors

- Implements most (if not all) applicable member functions from std::vector and std::array
- Compatible with C++11, C++14, C++17, C++20
- [] operator allows unchecked access, all other member functions throw

```
#ifndef STAT_VEC_H
#define STAT_VEC_H

#include <memory>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstring>
#include <iterator>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <type_traits>

// A growable, stack based vector

#if ((defined(_MSVC_LANG) && _MSVC_LANG >= 201703L) || __cplusplus >= 201703L)
#define STAT_VEC_HAS_CXX17 1
#endif

#if ((defined(_MSVC_LANG) && _MSVC_LANG >= 202002L) || __cplusplus >= 202002L)
#define STAT_VEC_HAS_CXX20 1
#endif

#ifdef STAT_VEC_HAS_CXX20
#define STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 constexpr
#else
#define STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 inline
#endif

#ifdef STAT_VEC_HAS_CXX17
#define STAT_VEC_NODISCARD [[nodiscard]]
#define STAT_VEC_BYTE_T std::byte
#else
#define STAT_VEC_NODISCARD
#define STAT_VEC_BYTE_T unsigned char
#endif

template <typename StaticVectorT>
class static_vec_const_iter {
public:
    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
    using value_type = typename StaticVectorT::value_type;
    using difference_type = ptrdiff_t;
    using pointer = const value_type*;
    using reference = const value_type&;

private:
    using arr_pointer = const StaticVectorT*;

    arr_pointer m_arr;
    size_t m_idx;

    void check_compat(const static_vec_const_iter& other) const
    {
        if (m_arr != other.m_arr) {
            throw std::logic_error("Non-compatible iterators");
        }
    }

    template <typename T, size_t Capacity>
    friend class static_vec;

public:
    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 explicit static_vec_const_iter(arr_pointer arr, size_t idx) noexcept : m_arr{ arr }, m_idx{ idx } {}

    STAT_VEC_NODISCARD STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 reference operator*() const
    {
        return *operator->();
    }

    STAT_VEC_NODISCARD STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 pointer operator->() const
    {
        if (m_idx >= m_arr->size()) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Cannot dereference out of range iterator");
        }
        return m_arr->data() + m_idx;
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 static_vec_const_iter& operator++()
    {
        if (m_idx >= m_arr->size()) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Cannot increment iterator past end");
        }
        ++m_idx;
        return *this;
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 static_vec_const_iter operator++(int)
    {
        static_vec_const_iter ret = *this;
        ++* this;
        return ret;
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 static_vec_const_iter& operator--()
    {
        if (m_idx == 0) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Cannot decrement iterator before end");
        }
        --m_idx;
        return *this;
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 static_vec_const_iter operator--(int)
    {
        static_vec_const_iter ret = *this;
        --* this;
        return ret;
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 static_vec_const_iter& operator+=(const ptrdiff_t offset)
    {
        if (offset < 0 && size_t{ ptrdiff_t{0} - offset } > m_idx) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Cannot decrement iterator before end");
        }
        if (offset > 0 && static_cast<size_t>(offset) > m_arr->size() - m_idx) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Cannot increment iterator past end");
        }
        m_idx += static_cast<size_t>(offset);
        return *this;
    }

    STAT_VEC_NODISCARD STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 static_vec_const_iter operator+(const ptrdiff_t offset)
    {
        static_vec_const_iter ret = *this;
        return ret += offset;
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 static_vec_const_iter& operator-=(const ptrdiff_t offset)
    {
        return *this += -offset;
    }

    STAT_VEC_NODISCARD STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 static_vec_const_iter operator-(const ptrdiff_t offset)
    {
        static_vec_const_iter ret = *this;
        return ret -= offset;
    }

    STAT_VEC_NODISCARD STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 ptrdiff_t operator-(const static_vec_const_iter& other) const
    {
        check_compat(other);
        return static_cast<ptrdiff_t>(m_idx - other.m_idx);
    }

    STAT_VEC_NODISCARD STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 reference operator[](const ptrdiff_t offset) const
    {
        return *(*this + offset);
    }

    STAT_VEC_NODISCARD STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 bool operator==(const static_vec_const_iter& other) const
    {
        check_compat(other);
        return m_idx = other.m_idx;
    }

    STAT_VEC_NODISCARD STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 bool operator!=(const static_vec_const_iter& other) const
    {
        check_compat(other);
        return m_idx != other.m_idx;
    }

    STAT_VEC_NODISCARD STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 bool operator<(const static_vec_const_iter& other) const
    {
        check_compat(other);
        return m_idx < other.m_idx;
    }

    STAT_VEC_NODISCARD STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 bool operator>(const static_vec_const_iter& other) const
    {
        check_compat(other);
        return m_idx < other.m_idx;
    }

    STAT_VEC_NODISCARD STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 bool operator<=(const static_vec_const_iter& other) const
    {
        check_compat(other);
        return m_idx <= other.m_idx;
    }

    STAT_VEC_NODISCARD STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 bool operator>=(const static_vec_const_iter& other) const
    {
        check_compat(other);
        return m_idx >= other.m_idx;
    }
};

template <typename StaticVectorT>
class static_vec_iter {
public:
    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
    using value_type = typename StaticVectorT::value_type;
    using difference_type = ptrdiff_t;
    using pointer = value_type*;
    using reference = value_type&;

private:
    using arr_pointer = StaticVectorT*;

    arr_pointer m_arr;
    size_t m_idx;

    void check_compat(const static_vec_iter& other) const
    {
        if (m_arr != other.m_arr) {
            throw std::logic_error("Non-compatible iterators");
        }
    }

    template <typename T, size_t Capacity>
    friend class static_vec;

public:
    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 explicit static_vec_iter(arr_pointer arr, size_t idx) noexcept : m_arr{ arr }, m_idx{ idx } {}

    STAT_VEC_NODISCARD STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 reference operator*() const
    {
        return *operator->();
    }

    STAT_VEC_NODISCARD STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 pointer operator->() const
    {
        if (m_idx >= m_arr->size()) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Cannot dereference out of range iterator");
        }
        return m_arr->data() + m_idx;
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 static_vec_iter& operator++()
    {
        if (m_idx >= m_arr->size()) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Cannot increment iterator past end");
        }
        ++m_idx;
        return *this;
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 static_vec_iter operator++(int)
    {
        static_vec_iter ret = *this;
        ++* this;
        return ret;
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 static_vec_iter& operator--()
    {
        if (m_idx == 0) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Cannot decrement iterator before end");
        }
        --m_idx;
        return *this;
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 static_vec_iter operator--(int)
    {
        static_vec_iter ret = *this;
        --* this;
        return ret;
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 static_vec_iter& operator+=(const ptrdiff_t offset)
    {
        if (offset < 0 && size_t{ ptrdiff_t{0} - offset } > m_idx) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Cannot decrement iterator before end");
        }
        if (offset > 0 && static_cast<size_t>(offset) > m_arr->size() - m_idx) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Cannot increment iterator past end");
        }
        m_idx += static_cast<size_t>(offset);
        return *this;
    }

    STAT_VEC_NODISCARD STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 static_vec_iter operator+(const ptrdiff_t offset)
    {
        static_vec_iter ret = *this;
        return ret += offset;
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 static_vec_iter& operator-=(const ptrdiff_t offset)
    {
        return *this += -offset;
    }

    STAT_VEC_NODISCARD STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 static_vec_iter operator-(const ptrdiff_t offset)
    {
        static_vec_iter ret = *this;
        return ret -= offset;
    }

    STAT_VEC_NODISCARD STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 ptrdiff_t operator-(const static_vec_iter& other) const
    {
        check_compat(other);
        return static_cast<ptrdiff_t>(m_idx - other.m_idx);
    }

    STAT_VEC_NODISCARD STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 reference operator[](const ptrdiff_t offset) const
    {
        return *(*this + offset);
    }

    STAT_VEC_NODISCARD STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 bool operator==(const static_vec_iter& other) const
    {
        check_compat(other);
        return m_idx == other.m_idx;
    }

    STAT_VEC_NODISCARD STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 bool operator!=(const static_vec_iter& other) const
    {
        check_compat(other);
        return m_idx != other.m_idx;
    }

    STAT_VEC_NODISCARD STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 bool operator<(const static_vec_iter& other) const
    {
        check_compat(other);
        return m_idx < other.m_idx;
    }

    STAT_VEC_NODISCARD STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 bool operator>(const static_vec_iter& other) const
    {
        check_compat(other);
        return m_idx < other.m_idx;
    }

    STAT_VEC_NODISCARD STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 bool operator<=(const static_vec_iter& other) const
    {
        check_compat(other);
        return m_idx <= other.m_idx;
    }

    STAT_VEC_NODISCARD STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 bool operator>=(const static_vec_iter& other) const
    {
        check_compat(other);
        return m_idx >= other.m_idx;
    }

    operator static_vec_const_iter<StaticVectorT>() const
    {
        return static_vec_const_iter<StaticVectorT>(m_arr, m_idx);
    }
};

template <typename T, size_t Capacity>
class static_vec {
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using pointer = T*;
    using const_pointer = const T*;
    using reference = T&;
    using const_reference = const T&;
    using size_type = size_t;
    using difference_type = ptrdiff_t;

    using iterator = static_vec_iter<static_vec>;
    using const_iterator = static_vec_const_iter<static_vec>;
    using reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<iterator>;
    using const_reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator>;

private:
    size_type m_size;
    alignas(T) STAT_VEC_BYTE_T m_data[sizeof(T) * Capacity];

    inline void check_not_full()
    {
        if (m_size >= Capacity) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Buffer is full");
        }
    }

    inline void check_not_empty()
    {
        if (m_size == 0) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Buffer is empty");
        }
    }

    inline void check_in_bounds(size_type idx)
    {
        if (idx >= m_size) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Out of bounds");
        }
    }

    inline void check_insert(size_type idx, size_type count)
    {
        if ((m_size + count) > Capacity) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Not enough room in buffer");
        }
        if (idx > m_size) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Out of bounds");
        }
    }

    inline void check_erase(size_type idx, size_type count)
    {
        if (m_size == 0) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Buffer is empty");
        }
        if (idx + count > m_size) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Out of bounds");
        }
    }

    template <class iterT>
    inline void check_iters(iterT first, iterT last)
    {
        if (std::distance(first, last) < 0) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Last iterator at or after first iterator");
        }
    }

    inline pointer unchecked_ptr_at(size_type idx)
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<T*>(&m_data[idx * sizeof(T)]);
    }

    inline const_pointer unchecked_ptr_at(size_type idx) const
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<const T*>(&m_data[idx * sizeof(T)]);
    }

    inline reference unchecked_at(size_type idx)
    {
        return *unchecked_ptr_at(idx);
    }

    inline const_reference unchecked_at(size_type idx) const
    {
        return *unchecked_ptr_at(idx);
    }

    template <class... U>
    using void_t = void;

    template <class U, class = void>
    struct is_input_iterator : std::false_type {
    };

    template <class U>
    struct is_input_iterator<U, static_vec::void_t<
        typename std::iterator_traits<U>::iterator_category,
        typename std::iterator_traits<U>::value_type,
        typename std::iterator_traits<U>::reference,
        typename std::iterator_traits<U>::difference_type,
        decltype(++std::declval<U&>()), // prefix incrementable,
        decltype(std::declval<U&>()++), // postfix incrementable,
        decltype(*std::declval<U&>()), // dereferencable via *,
        decltype(std::declval<U&>().operator->()), // dereferencable via ->,
        decltype(std::declval<U&>() == std::declval<U&>()) // comparable
    > > : std::true_type {
    };

    template <class U>
    using is_input_iterator_t = typename is_input_iterator<U>::type;

public:
    static_vec()
        : m_size{ 0 }
        , m_data{}
    {
    }

    ~static_vec()
    {
        clear();
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 reference at(size_type idx)
    {
        check_in_bounds(idx);
        return unchecked_at(idx);
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 const_reference at(size_type idx) const
    {
        check_in_bounds(idx);
        return unchecked_at(idx);
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 reference operator[](size_type idx)
    {
        return unchecked_at(idx);
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 const_reference operator[](size_type idx) const
    {
        return unchecked_at(idx);
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 reference front()
    {
        check_not_empty();
        return unchecked_at(0);
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 const_reference front() const
    {
        check_not_empty();
        return unchecked_at(0);
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 reference back()
    {
        check_not_empty();
        return unchecked_at(m_size - 1);
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 const_reference back() const
    {
        check_not_empty();
        return unchecked_at(m_size - 1);
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 pointer data() noexcept
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<T*>(m_data);
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 const_pointer data() const noexcept
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<const T*>(m_data);
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 iterator begin() noexcept
    {
        return iterator(this, 0);
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 const_iterator begin() const noexcept
    {
        return const_iterator(this, 0);
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 const_iterator cbegin() const noexcept
    {
        return const_iterator(this, 0);
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 iterator end() noexcept
    {
        return iterator(this, m_size);
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 const_iterator end() const noexcept
    {
        return const_iterator(this, m_size);
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 const_iterator cend() const noexcept
    {
        return const_iterator(this, m_size);
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 reverse_iterator rbegin() noexcept
    {
        return reverse_iterator(this, 0);
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const noexcept
    {
        return const_reverse_iterator(this, 0);
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const noexcept
    {
        return const_reverse_iterator(this, 0);
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 reverse_iterator rend() noexcept
    {
        return reverse_iterator(this, m_size);
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 const_reverse_iterator rend() const noexcept
    {
        return const_reverse_iterator(this, m_size);
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 const_reverse_iterator crend() const noexcept
    {
        return const_reverse_iterator(this, m_size);
    }

    STAT_VEC_NODISCARD STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 bool empty() const noexcept
    {
        return m_size == 0;
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 size_type size() const noexcept
    {
        return m_size;
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 size_type max_size() const noexcept
    {
        return Capacity;
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 size_type capacity() const noexcept
    {
        return Capacity;
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 void clear() noexcept
    {
        for (size_type i = 0; i < m_size; i++) {
            unchecked_at(i).~T();
        }
        m_size = 0;
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 iterator insert(const_iterator pos, const T& value)
    {
        check_insert(pos.m_idx, 1);
        m_size++;
        for (size_t i = m_size; i > pos.m_idx; i--) {
            std::memcpy(unchecked_ptr_at(i), unchecked_ptr_at(i - 1), sizeof(T));
        }
        new (unchecked_ptr_at(pos.m_idx)) T(value);
        return iterator(this, pos.m_idx);
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 iterator insert(const_iterator pos, T&& value)
    {
        check_insert(pos.m_idx, 1);
        for (size_t i = m_size; i > pos.m_idx; i--) {
            std::memcpy(unchecked_ptr_at(i), unchecked_ptr_at(i - 1), sizeof(T));
        }
        new (unchecked_ptr_at(pos.m_idx)) T(std::move(value));
        m_size++;
        return iterator(this, pos.m_idx);
    }

    iterator insert(const_iterator pos, size_type count, const T& value)
    {
        if (count > 0) {
            check_insert(pos.m_idx, count);
            for (size_t i = m_size; i > pos.m_idx; i--) {
                std::memcpy(unchecked_ptr_at(i + count - 1), unchecked_ptr_at(i - 1), sizeof(T));
            }
            for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                new (unchecked_ptr_at(pos.m_idx + i)) T(value);
            }
            m_size += count;
        }
        return iterator(this, pos.m_idx);
    }

    template <class InputIt, typename std::enable_if<static_vec::is_input_iterator_t<InputIt>::value, bool>::type = true>
    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 iterator insert(const_iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last)
    {
        check_iters(first, last);
        size_t count = std::distance(first, last);
        if (count > 0) {
            check_insert(pos.m_idx, count);
            for (size_t i = m_size; i > pos.m_idx; i--) {
                std::memcpy(unchecked_ptr_at(i + count - 1), unchecked_ptr_at(i - 1), sizeof(T));
            }
            for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                new (unchecked_ptr_at(pos.m_idx + i)) T(*(first + i));
            }
            m_size += count;
        }
        return iterator(this, pos.m_idx);
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 iterator insert(const_iterator pos, std::initializer_list<T> ilist)
    {
        if (ilist.size() > 0) {
            check_insert(pos.m_idx, ilist.size());
            for (size_t i = m_size; i > pos.m_idx; i--) {
                std::memcpy(unchecked_ptr_at(i + ilist.size() - 1), unchecked_ptr_at(i - 1), sizeof(T));
            }
            for (size_t i = 0; i < ilist.size(); i++) {
                new (unchecked_ptr_at(pos.m_idx + i)) T(*(ilist.begin() + i));
            }
            m_size += ilist.size();
        }
        return iterator(this, pos.m_idx);
    }

    template <class... Args>
    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 iterator emplace(const_iterator pos, Args&&... args)
    {
        check_insert(pos.m_idx, 1);
        for (size_t i = m_size; i > pos.m_idx; i--) {
            std::memcpy(unchecked_ptr_at(i), unchecked_ptr_at(i - 1), sizeof(T));
        }
        new (unchecked_ptr_at(pos.m_idx)) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        m_size++;
        return iterator(this, pos.m_idx);
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 iterator erase(const_iterator pos)
    {
        check_erase(pos.m_idx, 1);
        unchecked_at(pos.m_idx).~T();
        for (size_t i = pos.m_idx; i < m_size - pos.m_idx; i++) {
            std::memcpy(unchecked_ptr_at(i), unchecked_ptr_at(i + 1), sizeof(T));
        }
        m_size--;
        return iterator(this, pos.m_idx + 1);
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 iterator erase(const_iterator first, const_iterator last)
    {
        check_iters(first, last);
        size_t count = std::distance(first, last);
        if (count > 0) {
            check_erase(first.m_idx, count);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                unchecked_at(first.m_idx + i).~T();
            }
            for (size_t i = first.m_idx; i < m_size - first.m_idx; i++) {
                std::memcpy(unchecked_ptr_at(i), unchecked_ptr_at(i + count), sizeof(T));
            }
            m_size -= count;
        }
        return iterator(this, first.m_idx + count);
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 void push_back(const T& value)
    {
        check_not_full();
        new (unchecked_ptr_at(m_size)) T(value);
        m_size++;
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 void push_back(T&& value)
    {
        check_not_full();
        new (unchecked_ptr_at(m_size)) T(std::move(value));
        m_size++;
    }

    template <class... Args>
    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 T& emplace_back(Args&&... args)
    {
        check_not_full();
        auto ptr = unchecked_ptr_at(m_size);
        new (ptr) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        m_size++;
        return *ptr;
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 void pop_back()
    {
        check_not_empty();
        m_size--;
        unchecked_at(m_size).~T();
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 void fill(const T& value)
    {
        clear();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < Capacity; i++) {
            new (unchecked_ptr_at(i)) T(value);
        }
        m_size = Capacity;
    }

    STAT_VEC_CONSTEXPR_CXX20 void swap(static_vec<T, Capacity>& other) noexcept
    {
        size_t temp_size = 0;
        alignas(T) STAT_VEC_BYTE_T temp_data[sizeof(T) * Capacity];
        std::memcpy(temp_data, m_data, sizeof(T) * Capacity);
        std::memcpy(m_data, other.m_data, sizeof(T) * Capacity);
        std::memcpy(other.m_data, temp_data, sizeof(T) * Capacity);
        temp_size = m_size;
        m_size = other.m_size;
        other.m_size = temp_size;
    }
};

#endif /* STAT_VEC_H */
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Design

1. The reason for designing and using a fixed-capacity vector is generally efficiency. Forcing debug-iterators down the users throat breaks that. At least, make it opt-in, maybe following [MS iterator debug levels](//learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/checked-iterators).
2. If you use `VectorType` and `const VectorType` template arguments you can unify your checked iterators. Use `copy_const` and similar helpers:

   ```
   template <class T, class U>
   using copy_const_t = typename std::conditional<std::is_const<T>::value, const U, U>::type;
   ```

#### Implementation

1. You can strip all automatic handling for ctors/op=/dtors from a member by making it the sole member of an anonymous unnamed union without sacrificing ease of use.
   Specifically, it will cut down on casting required, thus you no longer have to hide the uglyness.
2. Don't extract all of a function into a differently named function. How far would you go? Any reader would have to understand (and check) your functions in addition to the (now) wrapper.
3. People expect object to be destructed in reverse order of construction. Thus, the highest index should be destroyed first, the lowest last, unless that causes unacceptable inefficiency.
4. Most objects might be bitwise movable or even bitwise copyable (trivially copyable), thus doing so with `std::memcpy()` might work for them, but it is generally wrong. Beware if there are pointers to the object (e.g. short `std::string` in GCC's libstdc++) or the objects value is position-dependent (any kind of relative pointer).
5. InputIterators only guarantee the sequence they provide can be iterated and read *once*.
6. Only RandomaccessIterators guarantee efficient distance-calculation, and freedom from UB even if negative. Test for the subtractibility directly, don't depend on the iterator category.